# What is the difference between referring to the model directly and using self in class methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-method

I'm trying to understand some code in Michael Hartl's awesome Rails Tutorial.

In ch 8, we add some class methods to the User model:

```
class User<ActiveRecord::Base
...
...

  before_create :create_remember_token
  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
      Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
```

What is the difference between doing this:

```
  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end
  ...

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
```

And this:

```
  def encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = self.encrypt(self.new_remember_token)
    end
```

If there is no difference, is there something that makes the former more desirable than the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a class definition (e.g. `class User ...`), `def encrypt ...` defines an *instance method*, whereas `def self.encrypt ...` defines a *class method*.

### Defining instance methods and class methods

Suppose we defined the User class like this:

```
class User
  def initialize(name)
    @name_instance_variable = name
  end

  # This is an instance method definition, creating a method called `encrypt`
  # on instances of the User class.
  def encrypt
    puts "Received User#encrypt instance method.\n" +
         "- `self` is an instance of #{ self.class }.\n" +
         "- `@name_instance_variable` is #{ @name_instance_variable.inspect }.\n"
  end

  # This is a class method definition, creating a method called `encrypt` on
  # the User class itself.
  def self.encrypt
    puts "Received User.encrypt class method.\n" +
         "- `self` is an instance of #{ self.class }.\n" +
         "- `@name_instance_variable` is #{ @name_instance_variable.inspect }.\n"
  end
end
```

#### Invoking an instance method

Now we can create an *instance* of User with the constructor `User.new`, which (automatically) invokes `initialize` above:

```
my_user = User.new("Tim")
```

In `initialize`, the value we gave to the constructor is assigned to the *instance variable* `@name_instance_variable`.

Now we can invoke *instance methods* on `my_user`, our *instance* of the User class:

```
my_user.encrypt
# => Received User#encrypt instance method.
#    - `self` is an instance of User.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is "Tim".
```

We can create another instance and give a different value to the constructor:

```
User.new("Jordan").encrypt
# => Received User#encrypt instance method.
#    - `self` is an instance of User.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is "Jordan".
```

#### Invoking a class method:

We can also invoke *class methods* on the User *class*:

```
User.encrypt
# => Received User.encrypt class method.
#    - `self` is an instance of Class.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is nil.
```

We get `nil` for `@name_instance_variable` because the *class* method does not have access to any of the *instances* we created, and we haven't done anything that would assign a value to it.

#### Another class method, and using one class method inside another

*After* we've created the User class, we can also define a new class method like this:

```
def User.create_remember_token
  puts "Received User.create_remember_token class method."

  # Now let's use the User.encrypt class method from within this method.
  encrypt

  # We could also write this, because inside this class method `self` refers
  # to the User class itself:
  #
  #   self.encrypt
  #
  # This is equivalent too--almost (the difference appears when you use
  # inheritance, i.e. create a subclass of User, but that's beyond the scope
  # of this answer):
  #
  #   User.encrypt
  #
end
```

...that's equivalent (but not necessarily preferable) to:

```
class User
  def self.create_remember_token
    # ...
  end
end
```

Now we have a `User.create_remember_token` class method, which works like this:

```
User.create_remember_token
# => Received User.create_remember_token class method.
#    Received User.encrypt class method.
#    - `self` is an instance of Class.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is nil.
```

#### Defining another instance method, and using instance methods inside other instance methods

Suppose we defined another instance method:

```
class User
  # An instance method this time:
  def create_remember_token
    puts "Received User#create_remember_token instance method.\n"
         "- `@name_instance_variable` is #{ @name_instance_variable }."

    encrypt

    # We could also write this, because inside this instance method `self`
    # refers to this instance of User:
    #
    #   self.encrypt
    #
  end
end
```

Now we have a `User#create_remember_token` instance method, which does this:

```
my_user = User.new("Alice")
my_user.create_remember_token
# => Received User#create_remember_token instance method.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is "Alice."
#    Received User#encrypt instance method.
#    - `self` is an instance of User.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is "Alice".
```

#### Using class methods within instance methods

Finally, there are two ways to invoke *class* methods from within *instance* methods. Suppose we defined our *instance* method like this instead:

```
class User
  def create_remember_token
    puts "Received User#create_remember_token instance method."
         "- `@name_instance_variable` is #{ @name_instance_variable }."

    # Since `self` refers to this instance of User, `self.class` equals
    # the User class itself.
    self.class.encrypt

    # That's is (almost) equivalent to this:
    #
    #     User.encrypt
    #
    # ("Almost" again because of the inheritance issue mentioned above.)
    #
  end
end
```

Now it will work like this:

```
User.new("Bob").create_remember_token
# => Received User#create_remember_token instance method.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is "Alice."
#    Received User.encrypt class method.
#    - `self` is an instance of Class.
#    - `@name_instance_variable` is nil.
```

Note that even though we invoked the *class* method `User.encrypt` inside of the *instance* method `User#encrypt`, the *instance variable* `@name_instance_variable` is still not available inside the *class method*.

#### When to use a class method

So why do class methods exist? Because you aren't always working with an *instance*.

There are good examples of this in Rails. Suppose we have a "Comment" model. `Comment#update_attributes` is an *instance method* because it works with an instance of Comment. It knows about the instance's attributes and its internal *state*. When you use `update_attributes` you know that you're making changes to that instance of Comment.

`Comment.find`, however, is a *class method*. When you use `Comment.find` you don't have an instance of Comment (yet). If `find` was an *instance* method we wouldn't be able to use it without first creating an instance:

```
id = 6
comment = Comment.new.find(id) # => #<Comment id: 6, ...>
```

...and that doesn't make much sense.

Rails could have done this another way, like defining a CommentFinder class, which makes a *little* more sense:

```
comment_finder = CommentFinder.new
comment = comment_finder.find(id) # => #<Comment id: 6, ...>
```

...and is actually pretty common in some languages (and even in some Ruby libraries; the popular [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) does this). But in Rails they've decided to make this simpler by making this functionality a *class method* of the Comment class, so we can just do this:

```
comment = Comment.find(id) # => #<Comment id: 6, ...>
```

### Final notes

1. You might've noticed that I keep referring to *instance methods* like this: `User#encode` and *class methods* like this: `User.encode`. This is a convention you'll see throughout Ruby and Rails' documentation and books and articles about both. A `#` after the class name means it's an instance method and a `.` means it's a class method.
2. Ruby is a "message-passing" language. You don't really need to worry about the distinction, but knowing this is handy because of some of the terminology you might run into. When we write `my_user.encode_video` we're technically *sending* the "message" `encode_video` to the `my_user` object. `my_user` *receives* the message `encode_video`.

   Colloquially, we often say "I *called* the `encode` method" or "this code *invokes* `encode`," and it's fine to use those terms instead (and in truth more developers will probably understand them). You'll probably find code before too long, though, that does something like `my_user.send(:encode_video)`, or even `type = "video"; ... my_user.send("encode_#{type}")` which makes more sense when you understand that "send" means "call" or "invoke."
3. Ruby is a very flexible language. Above in some of the output I wrote, "`self` is an instance of Class". That's not a mistake--in Ruby, even classes are objects, and any class you create will be an instance of the class named Class. There are even ways to define instance methods and instance variables on a class itself (rather than instances of it), but that's way beyond the scope of this answer. If you're dying of curiosity, google  "[eigenclass](https://www.google.com/search?q=eigenclass)."

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: thanks @Jordan - very thorough.  will take me a bit to get through it lol

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** - To answer the initial question, `def ClassName.method` is an explicit declaration of the class, `def self.method` is a class method referring to the class that the method is defined inside. I can't think of a use for `ClassName.method`, but I'm sure there is one somewhere in the broad broad scope of metaprogramming.

The difference is that

```
  def encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end
```

is an **instance method**. It can only be called on instances of a class (objects).

```
def User.encrypt(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end
```

is a **class method**. It can only be called on the class.

In an instance method, `self` refers to the instance, `ClassName` will **always** refer to the class. In a class method, `self` refers to the class.

The reason for the difference is **design pattern**. In this case, because the method never uses an instance of the `User` class, it's better left as a class method.

Comment: not entirely sure this clearly explains the difference.  reading your post, it doesn't tell me what the difference between `def Class.method` and `def self.method` is

Comment: You're not using the term [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) correctly. Class (or "static") methods feature prominently in some design patterns, but using class methods in the way you describe is not in and of itself a design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that self.method and Class.method are equivalent. Obviously if you wanted to mix code between multiple classes, you need to use self. Otherwise I think they are the same for all intents and purposes.